# ldd shows libm.so.6 but still linking with -lm is needed

Tags: c, gcc, linker, lm, ldd

I built a library and `ldd` shows that it references `libm.so.6`:

```
 ldd liba.so 
        ...  
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdf53e85000)
        ...
```

But when I compile my program I get:

```
$ gcc mytest.c -I/path/to/a/header -L/home/path/to/a/so  -la 
/usr/bin/ld: undefined reference to symbol 'sin@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//usr/lib64/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And only if I append `-lm` at the end of the latter command, the compilation succeeds.

Why is it so, if `libm.so.6` is shown by `ldd`? And why the error could contain `/usr/lib64/libm.so.6` instead of `/lib64/libm.so.6`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldd` lists the shared objects required by `liba.so` - something that'll be used by the dynamic linker ([`ld.so`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)). But the error you get is from the static linker ([`ld`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)).

That `liba.so` has a dependency on `libm.so` isn't relevant to `ld` when it attempts to resolve the symbols and link the executable together - despite the fact you link `liba.so`.

To `ld`, `liba.so` is another library to look at for unresolved symbols - it doesn't look at all dependencies of `liba.so`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But if I compile with g++ (without -lm), the compilation succeeds. Why is it so? I thought it's connected to the fact that libstdc++ references libm.

Comment: The `g++` frontend automatically links `libm.so` because the C++ standard library (`libstdc++`) needs it - but that's not the case with C library. Ideally, linking with the math library shouldn't be needed at all but for historical reasons.

Comment: I see. Thank you again!